# want alarm script to run in background but accept user input to stop it

Tags: bash

I hacked a perfectly simple yet effective alarm script found at http://milkteafuzz.com/j/2012/02/22/a-simple-bash-alarm-clock/ to accept user input when command is run at terminal that could be one of 3 params: alarm date-time, alarm sound file, or alarm title-msg to display. If no input is read then script prompts user for date-time for alarm using default sound file and alarm title-msg to display.

When alarm goes off I have a read command prompting user to hit the 'Enter' key to stop the alarm.

I want to have the script, when run, run in the background but still allow the user to stop the alarm (of course), but I cannot seem to implement the solution.

Here is what I have atm (omitting functions for brevity).:

```
echo ""

#'if' user input $1 is supplied
if [[ -n "$1" ]] ; then
    if [[ "$1" =~ [0-2]{0,1}[0-9][:]{1}[0-9]{1,2} ]] ; then     #'if' input $1 matches date-time format
        date="$1" #; echo "\$date: ${date}"
    elif [[ "$1" =~ ^.*\.(mp3|ogg)$ ]] ; then   #'if' input $1 has mp3/ogg ext
        fChkFile "$1"   #funct call
    else    #'else' it is assumed input $1 is alarm title-msg to display when alarm goes off 
        msg="$1" #; echo "\$msg: ${msg}"
    fi
fi

#'if' user input $2 is supplied
if [[ -n "$2" ]] ; then
    fInput23 "$2"   #funct call
fi

#'if' user input $3 is supplied
if [[ -n "$3" ]] ; then
    fInput23 "$3"   #funct call
fi

if [[ -z "$date" ]] ; then      #'if' date-format IS null then not detected from user input and so prompt user for one
    printf "What time should the alarm sound? "
    read date
    if [[ -z "$date" ]] ; then      #'if' "$date" IS still null then abort
        notify-send "Aborting. A date-time format is required and none was detected."
        exit 67
    fi
fi

if [[ -z "$msg" ]] ; then       #'if' title-message IS null then assign default
    msg="The time has arrived to sit up and take notice..." #; echo "\$msg: ${msg}"
fi

if [[ -z "$sndF" ]] ; then      #'if' sound file IS null then assign default
    sndF="/media/multiMediaA_intHdA720Gb/music/theStrokes_isThisIt/07_lastNite.mp3" #; echo "\$sndF: ${sndF}"
fi

echo -e "\n\t\033[1;36mOkay! Will alert you on:\033[1;32m" $(date --date="$date")"\033[0m\n"

sleep $(( $(date --date="$date" +%s) - $(date +%s) ));
notify-send "$msg" -t 0
#while true; do
    /usr/bin/mpg123 -q -l 0 "$sndF" &
    sleep 1
    read -ep $'\n\033[1;33mHit Enter key to stop the alarm.\033[0m\n' killAlm
    #almPid=$(ps aux|grep "\/usr\/bin mpg123"|cut -d' ' -f3) #; echo "\$almPid: ${almPid}"
    almPid=$(ps aux|grep "\/usr\/bin mpg123"|sed -r 's/^[^ \t]*[ \t]*([0-9]{3,5})[ \t]*.*$/\1/') #; echo "$almPid"
    kill "$almPid"
#done
```

The script as is runs fine and dandy, but I don't really like the idea of tying up a terminal for each alarm set (my memory is like a sieve and I tend to use multiple alarms at any given time). How might I run the script, accept input (date-time var at least) and then run in the BG, thus freeing up the terminal, but prompting the user to stop an alarm when one goes off?

**EDIT**:
Using screens works alright as mentioned in comment(s) below. But for some reason there are, all of a sudden (first time, since trying 'screen' solution), hung mpg processes that won't clear and so

```
kill "$almPid"
```

fails because it tries to clear a previous process now hung. So I added a loop to cycle thru all mpg pids killing each one in succession, which, although surely isn't pretty, seems to work. Good thing I use audacious for streaming music, so cycling thru to kill mpg pids doesn't break anything, unless of course there are multiple alarms sounding off at the same time I guess.

```
    #almPid=$(ps aux|grep "\/usr\/bin mpg123"|sed -r 's/^[^ \t]*[ \t]*([0-9]{3,5})[ \t]*.*$/\1/') #; echo "$almPid"
    for p in $(ps aux|grep "\/usr\/bin mpg123"|sed -r 's/^[^ \t]*[ \t]*([0-9]{3,5})[ \t]*.*$/\1/') ; do
        # echo "\$p: $p"
        kill "$p"
    done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with "screen" command

[exemple here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-screen-command-howto.html)

Comment: Also using a terminal emulator with tabs :) Although screen is more versatile.

Comment: the screen command is a kewl(ish) idea. I am superficially familiar with screen but never used it before. It is installed already so I went ahead and played with it and it works good; better than having a single terminal open per alarm (I use terminator, so single tab per alarm actually).

Comment: <Pause: 5 min edit timeout> But I had to add a 'for' loop since (I don't know why) there are hung mpg pids that won't clear (not sure if screen related or not) to kill the running mpg pid. Not ideal I am sure but works for now till I read/think of something better. Single tab for 'screen' command running multiple alarms works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to force the calling shell to bring the script into the foreground. Usually you would do this manually with `fg`, press enter, then use CRTL-Z to put it back into the background.

If the alarm is the only background job (or the most recent one) `fg` on its own is enough. If not you can see the job numbers of background processes with `jobs`. Supply the job number as an argument to `fg`.

Check out the 'JOB CONTROL' section of `man bash` for more information.